# Using Bluettoth not able to connect more than 4 slaves simultaneously to master- android

Tags: android, bluetooth, master-slave, android-bluetooth

I am following the android sample available for Bluetooth multi chat for my application.
First I was not able to make a single connection using the code but after i wrote `serverSocket.close();` after accepting in AcceptThread it is running fine.

I want to support 7 slaves to my Master-slave connection but it is not supporting more than 4 slaves. It appears that it is continuously listening to all the slaves like placed extra slaves in parking but not making connection, and once the previous connection breaks it connect the connect the one from parking.

Do any one have idea, please suggest me where to look at?

Answer (score 0):

For any one else looking for the same:

Now I am able to connect upto 7 device to my master. I just reversed the approach every one taken. Now my slave devices are listening for connection instead of master. master is issuing a connection thread for individual slaves and all slave devices have their own accept thread. this way master is not listening for all the 7 slaves to hit the connection.